# Подчеркивание комментариев в Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать подчеркивание комментариев в Eclipse?
Это очень надоедает и мне трудно читать комментарии.
Спасибо!!!

Comment: как писать с ошибками так нетрудно, а как читать и исправлять так пожалуйста

Answer (score 6):

`Window - Preferences - General - Editors - Text Editors - Spelling`

`Enable spell checking` - убрать галочку

Answer (score 2):

Поищите в настройках Spell Check и отключите.